# How do I ensure my MVC app redirects to an error page when a certain exception occurs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seen a nice example whereby the MVC controller class inherits from another controller class which handles an exception and returns a view with the error inside like so:

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        return View("NotFound");
    }

    public ActionResult InsufficientPriveleges()
    {
        return View("InsufficientPriveleges");
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception is NotFoundException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = NotFound();
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            return;
        }
        if (filterContext.Exception is InsufficientPrivelegesException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = InsufficientPriveleges();
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            return;
        }

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

However, I've noticed that say for example my controller is loading in a partial view for something the user should not have access to, the error will then be shown inside the partial view on the page.

I'd like the whole page to show the error, in effect the exception should redirect to a completely new page.  How can I achieve this using the current class shown above?

Comment: I think this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550995/get-filter-redirect-to-action

Comment: I can't seem to throw an exception inside a child action. I think I need to be able to throw an exception anywhere in the service layer regardless of where I am in the rendering pipeline and let a re-direct take place. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind showing the problematic partial view and related action? Maybe it's handled properly in case of partial view...

Comment: Yes in a Razor view I use Html.RenderAction().  This calls a child action on the controller to render a partial view.  On rendering a view, a service is called to get some data.  At this point the service may then throw an exception if the user is not allowed to view the data. I don't think MVC likes throwing an exception inside the rendering pipe-line.  Not sure how to get round this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mapping from HTTP result codes to specific error handlers in your web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Error/Unauthorized" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

and then create a custom error controller

```
public class ErrorController
{ 
        public ActionResult Index ()
        {
            return View ("Error");
        }

        public ActionResult Unauthorized ()
        {
            return View ("Error401");
        }

        public ActionResult NotFound ()
        {
            return View ("Error404");
    }
    }
```

and then throw an HttpException from your controllers

```
public ActionResult Test ()
{
    throw new HttpException ((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
}
```

another alternative is to use a custom [FilterAttribute](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2009/02/17/custom-authorization-with-aspnet-mvc/) to check permissions which throws a HttpException

```
[Authorize (Roles = SiteRoles.Admin)]
public ActionResult Test ()
{
  return View ();
}
```

Comment: See my comment above about throwing exceptions in child actions.

Comment: Update: the above works, but I might add that trying to raise exceptions inside a child action on the controller causes problems if you want to effectively render a new error page. I instead check and raise the exception from the main action on the controller rather than any of the child actions.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta handle ajax call differently. I would simply use error() of jquery $.ajax to handle that kind of ajax call error.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(g) {
          //process normal
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
          //process exception here
    }
})
```